# 'ffmpegkit/FFmpegKitConfig.h' file not found

Tags: flutter, dart

While trying to build my Flutter App in Xcode im getting following error

```
'ffmpegkit/FFmpegKitConfig.h' file not found
```

The App is running successfully in VS-Code .

I tried already hours to solve it. But I did not find any solution.

```
Flutter 2.10.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7e9793dee1 (3 months ago) • 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
Engine • revision bd539267b4
Tools • Dart 2.16.1 • DevTools 2.9.2
```

If more information needed please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue . The Problem was that for the package that I installed

```
https://pub.dev/packages/video_editor/example
```

I changed the iOS version in podfile to 13.0. And I forgot to change the version in my xcodeworkspace.